# Twocolumned document with twocolumned footnotes

Tags: multicol, reledmac

I want to create a document with a two-columned body and footnotes by using the packages `multicol` and `reledmac`.
But the columnwidth of the footnoter is divided by two when using `multicol`. How can I achieve a columnwidth of the footnote to be equal to that of the body?

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\Xarrangement[A]{twocol}
\Xcolalign{\justifying}
\numberlinefalse

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum*[1-2]\edtext{Lipsum}{
    \Afootnote{\lipsum*[3-4]}}
\lipsum*[5-6]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Leave out the `\Xarrangement[A]{twocol}`, because apparently it means two columns inside each multicol column. Reledmac seems not to be aware of `multicol`. And you should make the intercolumn space bigger to make place for the line numbers.

Comment: That was my first idea too, but leaving out the \Xarrangement[A]{twocol} prevents long footnotes from floating from one to the next column (leading to unbalanced footnotes). I edited my question to show the effect for long footnotes.

Comment: OK, then `\Xhsizetwocol{\columnwidth}` seems to be the command.

Comment: I confirm that should be the good command.

Comment: Yes. The column width is now as expected. But unfortunately paragraphs of the main body are moved to the next page leaving an empty space at the end of the second column (for larger footnotes) or the footnotes are leaving the page (at the bottom). So in my opinion reledmac doesn't work stable enough with multicol.